# Отчистка чата телеграмм бот aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, бот

Пожалуйста помогите сделать то что после команды /clear отчищался весь чат

Answer (score 1):

В Telegram есть ограничение, которое не позволяет ботам напрямую удалять историю чата. Можно через сохранения id сообщений, которые необходимо удалить, в базу данных. Затем бот может удалить сообщения через цикл запросов.

---

Пример удаления всех сообщений, через цикл (aiogram 3.x):

```
from aiogram.exceptions import TelegramBadRequest

@router.message(Command("clear"))
async def cmd_clear(message: Message, bot: Bot) -> None:
    try:
        # Все сообщения, начиная с текущего и до первого (message_id = 0)
        for i in range(message.message_id, 0, -1):
            await bot.delete_message(message.from_user.id, i)
    except TelegramBadRequest as ex:
        # Если сообщение не найдено (уже удалено или не существует), 
        # код ошибки будет "Bad Request: message to delete not found"
        if ex.message == "Bad Request: message to delete not found":
            print("Все сообщения удалены")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Создаете любую БД, которая вам нравится
2. Записываете в нее `id` всех отправляемых/получаемых сообщений
3. Пишите обычный хэндлер для команды `/clear`, который будет брать `id` сообщений из БД и удалять их с помощью `bot.delete_message(message_id)`
4. Очищаете БД

но имейте ввиду, что:

- Сообщение можно удалить только в том случае, если оно было отправлено менее 48 часов назад.
- Служебные сообщения о создании супергруппы, канала или темы форума не могут быть удалены.
- Сообщение с игральными костями в приватном чате может быть удалено только в том случае, если оно было отправлено более 24 часов назад.
- Боты могут удалять исходящие сообщения в приватных чатах, группах и супергруппах.
- Боты могут удалять входящие сообщения в приватных чатах.
- Боты, получившие `can_post_messages` разрешения, могут удалять исходящие сообщения в каналах.
- Если бот является администратором группы, он может удалить там любое сообщение.
- Если у бота есть разрешение на `can_delete_messages` в супергруппе или канале, он может удалить там любое сообщение.

*(взято из [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage))*

Comment: *Сообщение можно удалить только в том случае, если оно было отправлено менее 48 часов назад.
* - разве это не про "редактировать"? Поправьте, если не так.

Comment: внизу я специально привел ссылку на документацию по `deleteMessage`